# While loop not running correctly

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop to prompt account holder for info in Python. However, it works perfectly if a wrong info is entered by the account holder trying to log in - the system displays a message that asks user to re-enter info. But when user enters the right unfo, its still asking to re-enter account number.Can someone help point me in the right direction in order to get it working right? Here are the codes I wrote below:

```
#Account login.
#Allows user to  enter account info

print("\tWelcome to the 'Your account login'\n")
print("Please login using the form below.")


#If user's info is not correct, ask for repeat attempt

account_info = input("What is your account number?\n")

while account_info != int(input(123456789)):
    account_info = input("Please re-enter your account number :\n")

print("Here is your information")
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: I don't know Python, but that `int(input(...))` looks rather odd to me.  Why are you intifying (or calling `input`, for that matter) there and not doing the string that just got entered?

Comment: It should be `123456789 != int(account_info):`

Comment: I don't see the purpose of `int(input(123456789))`. It should probably read `while int(account_info) != 123456789:` i.e. comparing the input to that number.

Comment: I think you are mixing tabs and spaces. When I cut/paste, that final print is inside the while loop. If you cut/paste to get it here, that's it. Remove all tabs and only use spaces for indenting.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - no he's doing it properly (even though the prompt is a bit confusing). its the second prompt for the acct number and if it fails, he asks for the original again, then goes back to the while for the second entry.

Comment: the code works for me (after making sure the print is not in the while loop).

Comment: @tdelaney: You might want to change your definition of "works".  The user isn't supposed to be entering the same number twice -- especially with a prompt like `123456789`, which is too bizarre to be intentional.  They're supposed to be entering a number that then gets compared to `123456789`, until they enter the right number.

Comment: @cHao - I was referring to a potential subtle error _in the code as posted_. Your theory that he wants to compare all account numbers against 123456789 is silly. This is likely some hackup of his real code but since OP remains silent, we can only work off what we've seen.

Comment: @tdelaney: It's not silly at all, considering the context.  What we've seen, as the code comments spell out, is a newbie's first attempts at a login prompt.  At this stage of learning, it's actually *extremely* common to see input compared against a single hard-coded username, password, etc.  (Someone just starting out doesn't know better yet.  This will come soon enough, once the system needs more than a few logins.)